# Trying to get property 'name' of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\AppLaravel\resources\views\admin\editBill.blade.php)

Tags: php, html, laravel

I need to go to my bill list page but this error is stopping me: 'Trying to get property 'name' of non-object'

My route:

```
Route::get('bill/{id?}',[
'as'=>'bill',
'uses'=>'PageController@editBill'
```

]);

My Controller:

```
public function editBill($id)
{

    $customerInfo=DB::table('customer')->select('customer.id','customer.name','customer.created_at','customer.phone_number','customer.address','customer.note','bills.total','customer.email')->join('bills','bills.id_customer','=','customer.id')->where('customer.id', '=', $id)->first();

    $billInfo=Bill::where('id',$id)->get();

  
    return view('admin.editBill',compact('customerInfo','billInfo'));

   
}
```

My view:

```
<section class="content">
    <!-- Default box -->
    <div class="box">
        
        <div class="box-header with-border">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="container123  col-md-6"   style="">
                        <h4></h4>
                        <table class="table table-bordered">
                            <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th class="col-md-4">Customer Info</th>
                                <th class="col-md-6"></th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                             
                            <tr>
                                <td>Customer name</td>
                                <td>{{ $customerInfo->name }}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Date Order</td>
                                <td>{{ $customerInfo->created_at }}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Phone Number</td>
                                <td>{{ $customerInfo->phone_number }}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Address</td>
                                <td>{{ $customerInfo->address }}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Email</td>
                                <td>{{ $customerInfo->email }}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Note</td>
                                <td>{{ $customerInfo->note }}</td>
                            </tr>
                            
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <table id="myTable" class="table table-bordered table-hover dataTable" role="grid" aria-describedby="example2_info">
                        <thead>
                        <tr role="row">
                            <th class="sorting col-md-1" >Id</th>
                            <th class="sorting_asc col-md-4">Product name</th>
                            <th class="sorting col-md-2">Quantity</th>
                            <th class="sorting col-md-2">Unit_price</th>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        @foreach($billInfo as $key=>$bill)
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{ $key+1 }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $bill->product }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $bill->quantity }}</td>
                                <td>{{ number_format($bill->unit_price) }} VNĐ</td>
                            </tr>
                        @endforeach
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="3"><b>Total</b></td>
                            <td colspan="1"><b class="text-red">{{ number_format($customerInfo->total) }} đ</b></td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>

                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
            <form action="{{route('pdf',$customerInfo->id)}}" method="GET">

                <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
                {{ csrf_field() }}
                <div class="col-md-8"></div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-inline">
                        <label>Delivery Status: </label>
                        <select name="status" class="form-control input-inline" style="width: 200px">
                            <option value="1">None</option>
                            <option value="2">On going</option>
                            <option value="2">Delivered</option>
                        </select>

                        <input type="submit" method="get" value="Print" class="btn btn-primary">
                    </div>
                </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

The bill detail list is working fine but the customers detail is not

I tried others way like {{$customer->name ?? ''}} and it did't give an error anymore but it doesn't show any data

Comment: Your code doesn't make any sense. Is the ID being passed for a customer or a bill? You're using it for both. Why not just do either `$billInfo = Bill::find($id); $customerInfo = $billInfo->customer;` or `$customerInfo = Customer::find($id); $billInfo = $customerInfo->bills;`? Or better yet, just use route model binding to get rid of the lookups altogether.

Comment: Also you've made the route parameter optional, what happens when it's not passed?

Comment: @miken32 still get the same error $billInfo = Bill::find($id);   $customerInfo = $billInfo->bills;